# Is there a way to change all grammar errors that marked with a green line, without MS word to ask

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to change all Grammatical Errors / Punctuation,

**For example:**

```
" ." into "."

" ," into","

" :" into ":"

"two spaces" into "single space"
```

and any other error that MS word put *Green-line* under it. there is one way of doing so but it ask every time when it had to change.

```
       Sub Grammercheck()
       ActiveDocument.CheckGrammar
       End sub
```

So is there any other way to change All? without MS word asking every time.
[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwBb0.png)

Comment: Seems a job for AutoCorrect.

Comment: ...But I tested and " ," to "," is not accepted (Add button stays grey).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  if i use `Selection.Find.Replacement` then how do i put all of the above mention situations in one replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately AutoCorrect does not accept " ." to be replaced with ".". However, you can use the following procedure to replace these occurrences, for example when you are done with the document:

```
Sub replaceAll()
Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=" .", ReplaceWith:=".", _
        Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=" ;", ReplaceWith:=";", _
        Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

(Example taken directly from Word VBA documentation on Find Object, so "*If nothing helps, read the manual!*")

Comment: `Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=" .", ReplaceWith:=".", _
        Replace:=wdReplaceAll`
do The job just perfect. Don't need to add `myRange`

Answer (score 0):

I think following code cover most of Grammatical Errors / Punctuation,

@paul If there is another easy way let me know.

```
Sub replaceAll()
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=" .", ReplaceWith:=".", _
    Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=" ,", ReplaceWith:=",", _
    Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=" :", ReplaceWith:=":", _
    Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=" ;", ReplaceWith:=";", _
    Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="   ", ReplaceWith:=" ", _
    Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="  ", ReplaceWith:=" ", _
    Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="( ", ReplaceWith:="(", _
    Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=" )", ReplaceWith:=")", _
    Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=".  ", ReplaceWith:=". ", _
    Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```